# Javascript access nested HTML element from given Javascript object argument

Tags: javascript, html, onmouseover

I am trying to write a small script that will automatically reveals/hides the content of a div when the mouse gets over/out of it. What I wanna do is to have the title visible and when someone mouseover the title some more text to get visible.

The problem is that I want to show/hide only a specific inner div of any given element and not to hide the entire element. I do have lots of elements so to handwrite javascripts for every single of them is a bit silly

My HTML code goes like:

```
<li id="job1" onmouseover ="div2mouseover(this)"  onmouseout="div2mouseout(this)">
    <div style = "display:none" id="jobDescription">
        <p> Blablabla</p>
     </div>
<li>
```

My JavaScript code goes like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   function div2mouseover(obj) 
   {
        //obj.style.display = "none"; //I can reach that
        obj.getElementById("jobDescription").style.display = "initial"; //I can't reach that
   }
 </script>
```

So with the obj.style.display I can edit the visibility of any given element, but I can't reach its inner div that I am trying to reach.

I have managed to do that for a single element like this:

```
document.getElementById("jobDescription").style.display = "initial";
```

But with this way I have to write a script for all my job elements, which are a lot.
Any suggestions??

Comment: ID is supposed to be unique. Use a class instead, and use `obj.querySelector(".classNameHere")`

Comment: O man (or woman as might be), u are great!! worked like a charm.. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference elements by their position too.

For example if the div you want to display is always the first div inside the "hover" li you can do

```
function div2mouseover(obj) {
  var div = obj.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
  div.style.display = "initial";
}
```

You don't need any IDs in the divs if you do it like this.

Answer (score 0):

The comment from the friend nnnnnn solved my case.. (maybe the other answers might work as well)

ID is supposed to be unique. Use a class instead, and use obj.querySelector(".classNameHere") –  nnnnnn 12 mins ago

Thank you guys!